# Create an undirected connected graph from scratch

Tags: graph-theory

It's been a very long time since I looked at graph theory and my memory is hazy at best, wiped at worst. Basically, I have a network of 10 PCs. I want to connect each PC to 4 other PCs and then I want to optimize the longest induced path. My question is: how do I go about setting up such a graph? I.e. is there a convention how I should make the connections?

I thought about first assigning each of the 10 a random int between 1 and 10, while making sure no int repeats more than 4 times. Then during the second loop iterate over the first layer and assign a partner either based on the first layer if applicable or again randomly. Ex with 5 PCs:

```
1: 3 5   //because 1 was assigned to 5
2: 3 4   //random because 2 wasn't assigned
3: 5 1   //because 3 was assigned to 1
4: 5 2   //because we just assigned 4 to 2
5: 1 3   //because 5 was assigned to 3
```

This is fine for like <10 nodes but I wonder if there's a better way, perhaps an algorithm that could also optimize my induced path at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize the longest induced path"? Optimize how? Also, what is an induced path? (Induced subgraph that is a path?)

Comment: Do you mean to minimize it? Would choosing the central nose at random, and connecting every other node to it work for you? (A star graph) In this case the longest path would have the length of 2. Or is it the case that you need to keep a constant degree of 4?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to calculate a Graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$ and $\operatorname{deg}(v)=4 \textrm{ f.a. } v\in V$ so that $\operatorname{max} \{\operatorname{dist}(v,w): v,w \in V\}$ becomes minimal, where $\operatorname{dist}(v,w)$ is the length of a shortest path from $v$ to $w$. Is this correct? And do you care about complexity / running time as long as it is polynomial bounded?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so yes, I'm trying to do what S.M. Roch suggested. I don't primarily care about running time. How would I then go about doing that?

Comment: Aleks J, I need the degree of 4 to be satisfied for every node, which is why I don't see the star graph method working.

Comment: Ah, then I would just get the list of 4-regular graphs, and search for the one that maximises whatever properties you want. Here are some: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticGraph.html but there are other ways to list them (nauty, for example)

Comment: Gilleain, thanks for the answer. This is however specific to 4-regular, so a very narrow case. I was looking for more of a general "how to" that could apply to 3 or 5 or 6 connections. In the spirit of teach a man to fish rather than handing over the finch :)